# How to print the middle name in reverse order?

Tags: java, string

The problem I am having is that when I enter for example Gina Charlene Doe it will print out enelr.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class test_1
{
static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);     

public static void main() {
    String name, middle;
    System.out.println("Enter your first, middle, and last name ");
    name=in.nextLine();
    int space1=name.indexOf(" ");
    int space2=name.lastIndexOf(" ");

    middle=name.substring(space1+1,space2);

    for (int x=middle.length();x>=space1;x--)
    {
        System.out.print(middle.substring(x-1,x));
    }
}
}
```

Sorry I am new to posting things to here so I hope it's formatted well enough.

Comment: `x>=space1` should be `x > 0`.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your output, your loop is working but terminating too early. So something is wrong with your for loop

```
 for (int x=middle.length();x>=space1;x--)
```

Your condition, x>=space1, is the source of error because you set it to 5 here:

```
 int space1=name.indexOf(" ");
```

So in your loop, it works down your string from 8 and terminates when x = 4, which is midway through your string, obviously not what you want. So the correct fix is

```
for (int x=middle.length();x>0;x--)
```

Comment: Thank you, but now the output does put it in reverse but due to the .substring(x-1,x) it says that "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1"

Comment: Are you sure you changed it from >= to >? I imagine you're getting this error because x is managing to equal 0 and then you're trying to reference the -1 index of an array, which doesn't exist. You're going to want your loop to terminate when x = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is just logically flawed. Here is the correct code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Middle
{


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name, middle, reversed = "";
    System.out.println("Enter your first, middle, and last name ");
    name=in.nextLine();
    int space1=name.indexOf(" ");
    int space2=name.lastIndexOf(" ");

    middle=name.substring(space1+1,space2);

    for(int i=middle.length(); i > 0; i--)
    {
        reversed = reversed  + middle.charAt(i-1);
    }
    System.out.println(reversed);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Middle{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your first, middle and last name.");
        String[] name = in.nextLine().split(" ");

        for(int i=name[1].length()-1; i>=0; i--){
            System.out.print(name[1].charAt(i));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to print the middle name in reverse order?

**The straight answer is** `new StringBuilder(middle).reverse().toString();`

Solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    // input
    System.out.println("Enter your first, middle, and last name ");
    String fullname = in.nextLine();

    // split
    String[] fullnameArray = fullname.trim().split("\\s");

    // parse
    String first = fullnameArray[0];
    String middle = fullnameArray[1];
    String last = fullnameArray[2];

    // reverse middle name       
    String middleReversed = new StringBuilder(middle).reverse().toString();

    // output
    System.out.println("First name:" + first);
    System.out.println("middle name (reversed):" + middleReversed);
    System.out.println("last name:" + last);

}
```